# Passing multiple values for same variable in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a variable that passes multiple values to stored procedure.

When I see through fidler I see values being passed correctly like

```
    arg1=331
    arg1=222
    arg1=876
    arg1=932
```

In my stored procedure I am reading as

```
    procedure mainValues 
     @Arg1List     nvarchar(3000)
    as begin
  --Temp table to store split values
  declare @tmp_values table (
  value nvarchar(255) not null);   

   --function splitting values 
   insert into @tmp_values 
   select * from f_split(@Arg1List, ',');  

  --inserting in table value column is int.      
  insert into t_values (
   value
  )
  select 
  b.value
  from @tmp_values b;
```

When I test it, it doesn't add any values in t_values table. I checked the function etc. are all working fine. The problem is @Arg1List. It looks like stored procedure has no values in it. Please let me know how to declare @Arg1List properly so it takes multiple values as it seems to be the problem.

Comment: Are the values passed to variable Arg1List are comma dliminated like `'331,222,876,932'` ???? or is it a table of these values ??

Comment: Is the list of arguments being passed in as a single string parameter (e.g. "331, 222, 876, 932") or as 4 different parameters to the procedure?

Comment: And also how many columns this `f_split()` returns because normally these split functions return 2 columns, `INDEX` and a `Value` column

Comment: They are four different parameters

Comment: it is returning only one column of nvarchar.

Comment: @J.Davidson what is the link to the aforementioned fiddler?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do a couple of things to get this going, since your parameter is getting multiple values you need to create a Table Type and make your store procedure accept a parameter of that type.

Split Function Works Great when you are getting `One String` containing multiple values but when you are passing Multiple values you need to do something like this....

**TABLE TYPE**

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.TYPENAME AS TABLE 
 (
    arg int 
  )
 GO
```

**Stored Procedure to Accept That Type Param**

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE mainValues 
 @TableParam TYPENAME READONLY
 AS 
   BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
  --Temp table to store split values
  declare @tmp_values table (
  value nvarchar(255) not null);   

   --function splitting values 
   INSERT INTO @tmp_values (value)
   SELECT arg FROM @TableParam


   SELECT * FROM @tmp_values  --<-- For testing purpose
END
```

**EXECUTE PROC**

Declare a variable of that type and populate it with your values.

```
 DECLARE @Table TYPENAME     --<-- Variable of this TYPE

 INSERT INTO @Table                --<-- Populating the variable 
 VALUES (331),(222),(876),(932)

EXECUTE mainValues @Table   --<-- Stored Procedure Executed
```

**Result**

```
╔═══════╗
║ value ║
╠═══════╣
║   331 ║
║   222 ║
║   876 ║
║   932 ║
╚═══════╝
```

Comment: +1 for table types.  Seems like the perfect scenario to use them.  Note that it is a little difficult to change them once defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your stored procedure is designed to accept a single parameter, Arg1List.  You can't pass 4 parameters to a procedure that only accepts one.

To make it work, the code that calls your procedure will need to concatenate your parameters into a single string of no more than 3000 characters and pass it in as a single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Well, without a bigger view of your exact setup, how this is being called and what is happening in f_split it can be hard to debug the situation as I am basically just guessing. I can, however, offer an alternative solution that doesn't involve UDFs but rather relies on SQL Server's build in mechanisms... XML.

The below proc declaration accepts an XML type parameter called @parmsXML. This would replace your @Arg1List parameter. When you EXEC dbo.mainValues, you supply the @parmsXML parameter as a string of XML nodes rather than a comma separated list (I assume this is what you are doing but from your question it is not exactly clear):

```
<parms>
    <parm>331</parm>
    <parm>222</parm>
    <parm>876</parm>
    <parm>932</parm>
</parms>
```

The stored proc does this:

1. Just selects the values from from the @parmsXML variable directly
2. SELECTs the values from the @parmsXML variable into a temp #t_values table
3. SELECTs from the #t_values table

In your own implementation, you could get rid of the first step (Just select....), then change the SELECT INTO into a INSERT INTO SELECT.

I have the below script setup so that it will DROP IF EXISTS then CREATE the proc and then EXECUTE it with the @parmsXML setup as above.

```
--========================================================================================================================
/* DROP AND RECREATE PROC                                                                                               */
--========================================================================================================================

IF EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
   WHERE SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = N'dbo'
     AND SPECIFIC_NAME = N'mainValues' 
)
   DROP PROCEDURE dbo.mainValues
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.mainValues
    @parmsXML XML
AS

--========================================================================================================================
/* INTERPRETER DIRECTIVES                                                                                               */
--========================================================================================================================

SET NOCOUNT ON;    -- Turn off "(N row(s) affected)" messages
SET XACT_ABORT ON; -- Auto ROLLBACK on exception

--========================================================================================================================
/* PARMS PROCESSING                                                                                                     */
--========================================================================================================================

-- select from @parmsXML

RAISERROR('Selecting values directly from @parmsXML', 0, 1);

SELECT Parm = n.x.value('.[1]', 'INT')
FROM @parmsXML.nodes('/parms[1]/parm') n(x)
;

-- insert into

RAISERROR('Inserting @parmsXML values into #t_values', 0, 1);

SELECT Parm = n.x.value('.[1]', 'INT')
INTO #t_values
FROM @parmsXML.nodes('/parms[1]/parm') n(x)
;

-- select from #t_values

RAISERROR('Selecting from #t_values', 0, 1);

SELECT * 
FROM #t_values
;


GO

--========================================================================================================================
/* Example EXEC code runs stored proc with @parmsXML supplied                                                           */
--========================================================================================================================

EXECUTE dbo.mainValues @parmsXML = '
    <parms>
        <parm>331</parm>
        <parm>222</parm>
        <parm>876</parm>
        <parm>932</parm>
    </parms>
    '
GO
```