# How to set a value with the return value of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure SP1 that receives a parameter @param1 and does a bunch of things with it and returns a value.

Now I have a table consisting of two columns, say C1 and C2. Initially, C1 has different values on each row while C2 is 0 on every row. Now I want to update C2 with the value returned by SP1 with its corresponding C1 value as @param1. I was hoping something like:

```
update Table1 set C2 = (exec SP1 @param1=C1)
```

just like receiving a return value from a function in most programming languages.

I haven't learned any SQL, but I did a lot of research not finding anything. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the table update right into the stored procedure?

Comment: @tkendrick20 Even that I don't know how to do. Since I need to update each row respectively, how can I select each row and call the stored procedure? Looping over all the rows?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, The value returned from your stored procedure is a Single value and what rows you want to update in your table1 ?? or do you want to update column C2 for all the rows with the value returned by the stored procedure ??

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the "bunch of things" that your SP does, you may just be able to incorporate the SP into the update, or the update into the SP

Comment: @M.Ali Yes all the rows. But the value returned by the SP depends on the value of C1 on that row. So the return value will be different for each row.

Comment: What does your procedure returns a table or a single value ???

Comment: @M.Ali A single value

Comment: One column provides the input and the second column is where the output should go. If the OP can provide more detail about that is happening inside the proc, you can probably do this more efficiently... instead of calling the proc iteratively for each row in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an [`OUTPUT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) parameter inside your stored procedure and use that Parameter to store the value and then use that parameter inside your Update statement. Something like this....

```
DECLARE @OutParam Datatype;

EXECUTE SP1 @param1=C1, @OUT_Param = @OutParam OUTPUT  --<--

--Now you can use this OUTPUT parameter in your Update statement.

UPDATE Table1 
SET C2 = @OutParam
```

**UPDATE**

After reading your comments I think this is what you are trying to do pass value of C1 Column from Table Table1 to Stored Procedure and then Update the Relevant C2 Column of Table1 with the returned value of stored procedure.

For this best way to do is to Create a Table Type Parameter and pass the values of C1 as a table. [`See here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864093/passing-multiple-values-for-same-variable-in-stored-procedure) for a detailed answer about how to pass a table to a stored procedure.

I havent tested it But in this situation I guess you could do something like this.. I dont recomend this method if you have a large table. in that case you are better off with a table type parameter Procedure.

```
-- Get C1 Values In a Temp Table

SELECT DISTINCT C1 INTO #temp
FROM Table1

-- Declare Two Varibles 
--1) Return Type of Stored Procedure
--2) Datatype of C1

DECLARE @C1_Var DataType;
DECLARE @param1 DataType;

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #temp)
BEGIN
     -- Select Top 1 C1 to @C1_Var
      SELECT TOP 1 @C1_Var = C1 FROM #temp

      --Execute Proc and returned Value in @param1
      EXECUTE SP1 @param1 = @C1_Var 

      -- Update the table
      UPDATE Table1
      SET   C2 = @param1
      WHERE C1 = @C1_Var

      -- Delete from Temp Table to entually exit the loop
      DELETE FROM  #temp WHERE C1 =  @Var    

END
```

Comment: This won't do what he wants. He requires a value based on the C1 field value.

Comment: Yeah, that will apply the same value to each row, won't it? Rather than performing the SP for each row

Comment: the update table command is dynamic, it evaluates C1 for each row.

Comment: @Xufeng Well can you show the complete UPDATE statement. because what you were trying to do in your question I have done that. Now if your question extends you need to provide more information about it.

Comment: @M.Ali This is the complete update statement. But this single statement updates all the rows in the table.

Comment: Can to elaborate what do you mean by the value retunred by stored procedure depends on the value of C1 ?? can you show some sample data and demostrate what do you mean by this. A verbal description is very helpful in this case.

Comment: If it returns a single value then output parameter is the way to go, Once you have the value in OUTPUT parameter then you can use `IF..ELSE` blocks and place your update statement inside the `IF..ELSE` blocks of you can use `CASE` statement inside you `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: @M.Ali what he means is that the stored proc will return a different result depending on different param1 value. Since in this case the parameter value is an actual datafield value, the procedure must be executed as much as there's rows.

Comment: About your edit: mileage may vary here, depending on how the stored proc (and the ones it calls) are made. But yeah, it's an interesting approach. :)

Answer (score -2):

You can't use stored procedures like that.

What you will have to do is moving your stored procedure code into an UDF function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FN1 (@funcParam1 <param type>)
RETURNS <return type>
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @return <return type>;

    -- Do whatever you have to do here

    RETURN @return;
END
```

From then on you could do this:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET C2 = FN1(C1)
```

Please be aware though that this kind of practice can be bad on performance if the function is non-deterministic. Read about [deterministic and non-deterministic functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214775%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: You cannot execute a stored procedure inside a UDF.

Comment: It says declaration of FN1 must be in a batch by itself. So I created it in another file, now how to call it? It says FN1 is not built-in

Comment: @Xufeng, execute the CREATE FUNCTION code in another request (don't forget to look at my edited answer). AFTER THAT you will be able to use it in any query.

Comment: @Crono So there can't be any exec inside UDF? But the original SP1 does execute other stored procedures.. This is company code, so it's really messy... :(. Any workaround?

Comment: You could use OPENROWSET inside the function. It's hacky and unperformant but it might do the job for you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms190312.aspx

Comment: @Downvoters please do not keep your wisdom to yourself and share it. Thanks.